# C# AWS Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

When I publish my app to my server, and call a function which is dealing with Amazon SQS, I'm getting the following error:

```
ErrorMessage: "Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK, Version=1.5.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f476d3089b52be3' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

However the same method works fine in the localhost.

How should I solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you probably have a different version of the file.  If you look at the assembly version of AWSSDK.dll on your server, is it 1.5.19?

Answer (score 5):

Most common cause is the `.dll` is not present in the bin folder of your publish web-site.

Verify that the bin folder contains the `AWSSDK.dll` file.

You can ensure that the `.dll` is copied by setting the "Copy Local" proprety of your reference to `true`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the MysticMind port of the HtmlAgilityPack

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MysticMind.HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Access is denied.
```

The problem was the version number - the [nuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MysticMind.HtmlAgilityPack/1.0.0) is tagged as version 1.0.0, but in the [.csproj file of the source](https://github.com/mysticmind/mysticmind-htmlagilitypack/blob/master/src/MysticMind.HtmlAgilityPack/MysticMind.HtmlAgilityPack.csproj) I found that the actual version was 1.4.9.4 (the version of the upstream package).  I fixed it by changing the version number in my own .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

My DLLs were being copied to the bin properly but I was still getting the error.

My project was in SVN I resolved this by getting a fresh copy of the dll from svn and then doing a clean and build.

Seems somehow the dlls got corrupted or something.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened because my App.config file contained:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK"/>
</configSections>
```

I included it blindly from the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Amazon/TAWSConfigs.html). It has a new example on the top but the old ones are in the examples below. The right way now is:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK.Core"/>
</configSections>
```

I sent feedback to AWS (March 21, 2022) and hope they will fix it soon